# Convert UIImage to NSString (and vice-versa)

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsstring, uiimage

I need a method to convert a UIImage in a NSString and then convert the NSString back to a UIImage.

Thanks.

Comment: image name? path? url? image data as base64? What do you try to do?

Answer (score 12):

for >= IOS 7

```
- (NSString *)imageToNSString:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    return [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}

- (UIImage *)stringToUIImage:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:string
                                                  options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a binary stream instead (`NSData`). This will depend on the format of your `UIImage`. If it's a JPEG/PNG for instance, you do:

```
NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

UPDATE: Converting the binary data to `NSString` is a bad idea, that is why we have the class `NSData`. The OP wants to be able to send it as a data stream and then reconstruct it again; `NSString` will not be needed for this.

Comment: Did you check that you got a valid NSData object first? The UIImage*Representation will return nil if the UIImage is in an unsupported format.

Comment: The image is valid. The NSData is valid too.

Comment: I got a valid NSString using [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64Encoding]. Now, all I need is a way to convert a Base 64 encoded NSString in a NSData.

Comment: All you need is in NSString: `-dataUsingEncoding:` and `-initWithData:encoding:`

Comment: It isn't working. The result of the UIImage (after converting) is (null).

Comment: Not sure if you will succeed in fitting binary data into an NSString. It doesn't sound like a good idea, since that is what NSData is for in the first place. Why do you need it as an NSString?

Comment: So, is there a way to pass as parameter the memory address of the UIImage and length and then recreate the UIImage in the other side?

Comment: Then NSData will do just fine.

Comment: What is the other side? How are you sending this data? This might be a question in itself, but if you are sending this through a network protocol, I'm sure it will allow sending binary data.

Comment: The data is being send as a pure string. I can just pass a pure NSString. I have an UIImage, I need to convert it to a NSString, pass this NSString to other process (using IPC) and then recreate the UIImage using the NSString.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea. Sure, it's theoretically possible, you just have to write your own format of storing binary data in an NSString. But I strongly discourage it. I suggest formulating a new question, detailing your threads and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to PNG or JPEG using UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRepresentation, which will return an NSData, and then convert the NSData to a string (not sure how you want to do that mapping). How about just dealing with the NSData? You can read/write that to a file.

Comment: I don't want to write to the disk because the I/O latency is too high.

Comment: I want to write a string and a nsdata in to a file, how is that possible? any ideas?