# Converting image to NSData & back is nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, nsdata

When I do

```
UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_thumbnail.png"];
self.thumbnail.image = photo;
```

I see the thumbnail, which is a `PNG`, fine. When I convert to NSData & back by doing:

```
UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_thumbnail.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo);
self.photoData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.photoData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

`self.photoData` is nil.

Why is this happening?

Comment: 1) you can't convert image data to a string like that. 2) you can't assign an NSString value to a property expecting a UIImage.

Comment: @rmaddy 1:) why not? #2 was a typo.

Comment: Because the data represents image data, not a UTF-8 encoded string. You need to do some base 64 encoding.

Comment: @quantumpotato 1.) For instances of `NSData` every bit combination is valid. That's not true for UTF-8 strings. Beside this, UTF-8 sting can be normalized, changing the binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the way you create your image back from NSData instance. Give it a try to this one instead:

```
UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_thumbnail.png"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

**__UPDATE__**

below is an excerpt from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849636/convert-uiimage-to-nsstring-and-vice-versa)

```
- (NSString *)imageToNSString:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    return [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}

- (UIImage *)stringToUIImage:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:string
                                                  options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: I need to simulate converting to String because I am going to receive a PNG representation of the image as JSON from a server.

Comment: @quantumpotato I bet you have seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849636/convert-uiimage-to-nsstring-and-vice-versa) but just in case you have not. =]

Comment: I was just there testing out the base64 encoded.. same issue. I'm reviewing.

Comment: did you try ? It takes 2 mins to try it out. =] I put the part that I think you should give it a go in my answer. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Hey it worked! I didn't have the decodingIgnore part.... do you know why that option should be required?

Comment: Hm I spoke to soon... extracting the code.. testing

Comment: To be honest, it has been a while since the last time I dealt with ObjC. I can't tell off the top of my head. So need to look it up.So can you. Sorry.